# Is there a way to filter <engineername>.startupname.com, but not <specificurl>.startupname.com, in Google Analytics?

Tags: filter, google-analytics, metrics

I just started at a start-up in a non-technical role.

Recently, we noticed that our GA data is being corrupted during WFH by local dev testing. When our engineers use local dev, their URLs come in as engingeername.startupname.com. I would like to know how to make a filter that excludes all such URLs from GA data (so, for example, jennifer.startupname.com wouldn't be included).

Here's the tricky part. We want to include blog traffic, and our blog traffic comes in as blog.startupname.com. So whatever filters I put on would have to make an exception for such blog URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a predefinite filter that include traffic only to that subdomain, like this:

[image]